# Spark StructuredStreaming - watermark not working as expected

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, watermark

I've a structured Streaming job which has a trigger of 10 minutes, and I'm using watermark to account for late data coming in.
However, the watermark is not working - and instead of a single record with total aggregated value, i see 2 records.

Here is the code :

```
1) StructuredStreaming - Reading from Kafka every 10 mins


        df_stream = self.spark.readStream.format('kafka') \
            .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL") \
            .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", self.ssl_truststore_location) \
            .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", self.ssl_truststore_password) \
            .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", self.ssl_keystore_location_bandwidth_intermediate) \
            .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", self.ssl_keystore_password_bandwidth_intermediate) \
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", self.kafkaBrokers) \
            .option("subscribe", topic) \
            .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
            .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \
            .option("kafka.metadata.max.age.ms", "1000") \
            .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.type", "PKCS12") \
            .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.type", "PKCS12") \
            .load()


2. calling foreachBatch(self.process)
        # note - outputMode is set to "update" (tried setting outputMode = append as well)

        # 03/09 ::: outputMode - update instead of append
        query = df_stream.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "timestamp", "topic").writeStream \
            .outputMode("update") \
            .trigger(processingTime='10 minutes') \
            .option("truncate", "false") \
            .option("checkpointLocation", self.checkpoint) \
            .foreachBatch(self.process) \
            .start()


self.process - where i do the bulk of the  processing, which calls the function  'aggIntfLogs'

In function aggIntfLogs - i'm using watermark of 15 mins, and doing  groupBy to calculate the sum of sentOctets & recvdOctets
        
        
        def aggIntfLogs(ldf):
            if ldf and ldf.count() > 0:
   
                ldf = ldf.select('applianceName', 'timeslot', 'sentOctets', 'recvdOctets','ts', 'customer') \
                    .withColumn('sentOctets', ldf["sentOctets"].cast(LongType())) \
                    .withColumn('recvdOctets', ldf["recvdOctets"].cast(LongType())) \
                    .withWatermark("ts", "15 minutes")

                ldf = ldf.groupBy("applianceName", "timeslot", "customer",
                                                             window(col("ts"), "15 minutes")) \
                    .agg({'sentOctets':"sum", 'recvdOctets':"sum"}) \
                    .withColumnRenamed('sum(sentOctets)', 'sentOctets') \
                    .withColumnRenamed('sum(recvdOctets)', 'recvdOctets') \
                    .fillna(0)
                return ldf
            return ldf           
            
        
        Dataframe 'ldf' returned from the function aggIntfLogs - is written to Kafka topic
```

I was expecting that using the watermark will account for late coming data .. i.e. the sentOctets & recvdOctets are calculated for the consolidated data
(inclusing late-coming data, since the late coming data comes within 15 mins), however, I'm seeing 2 records for some of the data (i.e. key - applianceName/timeslot/customer) i.e. the aggregated data is calculated individually for the records and I see 2 records instead of single record accounting for late coming data within watermark.

What needs to be done to fix/debug this & make this work as desired?

tia!

Answer (score 0):

watermark tells system how much  late data will be considered as part of stream and older than that it will be rejected

now if you have 2 different timestamp then as you are aggregating by timestamp you will get 2 records that has noting to do with watermark

if you want one record make timestamp as 15th minute part of hour so all timestamp in that window  will have one timestamp.